# AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT functions in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, aes

I was trying the functions AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT in MYSQL 8.0.19. 
When I run `SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('foo','test');` I get `0x429292F7734FFE002C4E5B11239FD3A4`, but when I run `SELECT AES_DECRYPT('0x429292F7734FFE002C4E5B11239FD3A4','test');` I get `0x` (instead of `'foo'`).
Why is the AES_DECRYPT function not working?
Thank you all. Kind regards. NC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input of `aes_decrypt()` needs to be a binary string not a character string. Since the return value of `aes_decrypt()` is also a binary string, you might need to cast it to a character string.

Either don't quote the input.

```
SELECT cast(aes_decrypt(0x429292F7734FFE002C4E5B11239FD3A4, 'test') AS char);
```

Or remove the leading `'0x'` an prefix an `x`.

```
SELECT cast(aes_decrypt(x'429292F7734FFE002C4E5B11239FD3A4', 'test') AS char);
```

Or remove the leading `'0x'` and `unhex()` on the (character) string.

```
SELECT cast(aes_decrypt(unhex('429292F7734FFE002C4E5B11239FD3A4'), 'test') AS char);
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when I try one of the three above, I don't get `foo` but `0x666F6F`. When I try to unhex this, I get `0x`. When I try this web service - [link](https://www.browserling.com/tools/hex-to-text) - I get "foo" successfully. I don't understand why the function doesn't work. I've also searched for help in the MySQL documentation but found no help.

Comment: @NiccolòCavallini: The function does work. You just need to understand that binary strings aren't character strings and that these encryption functions primarily work on primary strings.That `unhex()` on a binary string doesn't work is also not too surprising, it expects a character string. See the edit, I added the casting.

Comment: @NiccolòCavallini if it "works like a charm" please accept this answer.